Related to Slack files.completeUploadExternal. I can't upload video file to the Slack using GAS
The programming language used is JavaScript in Google Apps Script.
I want to upload video files stored in Google Drive to Slack.
I would like to send someone a DM.
This is the code:
function myFunction() {
  let token = "Slack_Bot_User_Outh_Token"
  let bot_token = "Slack_User_Outh_Token"
  let user_id = "slack_user_id"

  let user_channel_original_id = get_user_channel_id(token, user_id)
  let file_info = DriveApp.getFileById("Drive_file_id")
  let slack_file_uploaded_id = get_upload_url(token, file_info)
  post_slack_to_person(token, slack_file_uploaded_id, user_channel_original_id)
}

function get_user_channel_id(token, user_id) {
  let slack_conversion_url = "https://slack.com/api/conversations.open"
  let options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": {
      "token": token,
      "users": user_id
    }
  }
  let res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(slack_conversion_url, options)
  let user_channel_id = JSON.parse(res.getContentText()).channel.id
  return user_channel_id
}

function get_upload_url(token, file_info) {
  let send_toslack_url = "https://slack.com/api/files.getUploadURLExternal"

  let options = {
    "method": "get",
    "payload": {
      "token": token,
      "filename": file_info,
      "length": file_info.getSize().toString(),
    }
  }
  let res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(send_toslack_url, options)
  return JSON.parse(res).file_id
}

function post_slack_to_person(token, file_id, channel_id) {
  let post_directmessages = "https://slack.com/api/files.completeUploadExternal"

  let options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
    },
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(
      {
        files: [
          {
            "id": file_id,
          }
        ],
        "channel_id": channel_id,
      },
    )
  }
  let res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(post_directmessages, options)
  Logger.log(res)
  return res
}

And this is response.
{
  "ok": true, "files": [
    {
      "id": "I can't show you",
      "created": 1716643818,
      "timestamp": 1716643818,
      "name": "TEST.mp4",
      "title": "TEST.mp4",
      "mimetype": "",
      "filetype": "",
      "pretty_type": "",
      "user": "I can't show you",
      "user_team": "I can't show you",
      "editable": false,
      "size": 13659221,
      "mode": "hosted",
      "is_external": false,
      "external_type": "",
      "is_public": false,
      "public_url_shared": false,
      "display_as_bot": false,
      "username": "",
      "url_private": "I can't show you",
      "url_private_download": "I can't show you",
      "media_display_type": "unknown",
      "permalink": "I can't show you",
      "permalink_public": "I can't show you",
      "comments_count": 0,
      "is_starred": false,
      "shares": {},
      "channels": [],
      "groups": [],
      "ims": [],
      "has_more_shares": false,
      "has_rich_preview": false,
      "file_access": "visible"
    }
  ],
  "warning": "missing_charset",
  "response_metadata": {
    "warnings": [
      "missing_charset"
    ]
  }
}

Documentation: https://api.slack.com/methods/files.completeUploadExternal https://api.slack.com/methods/files.getUploadURLExternal

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

files.getUploadURLExternal response has upload_url and file_id.
Send a POST request to upload_url with your file before use files.completeUploadExternal
# python code
res = req.post(
    url=upload_url,
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {slack_bot_token}"},
    files=files,
)

